# Calculating Routes with concatenated Pascal's Triangles and Fixed Direction

Tags: combinatorics

Calculate how many possible routes there are from the blue dot to a red dot (see the picture below).
The right answer is $N=2\binom{11}{6}*2^3=7392$. Please describe how the formula relates to the picture below.

[image: two muppets]

Comment: Are we allowed to go only towards the right?

Comment: Consider the two points where the figures meet. Call them $P$ and $Q$. How many ways to get from blue to $P$? By symmetry we have the same number of ways to get to $Q$. Now for each of these, count the number of ways to get to red.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, you can move only from the blue dot towards a red dot. It's about the shortest possible route.

Comment: Ok, then you reach a red dot in fourteen steps, no matter which route did you take any time. In almost every point  you can take two different routes - right up or right down, so you just have to track in which cases you have a forced choice.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You've chosen the right direction for the answer to this problem. If you could elaborate your way with an answer to the actual problem, it would be great.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It's a way to solve this problem but there is a simpler way using symmetry.

Comment: It looks like you already know an elegant solution, so why asking for help?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know how to solve this mathematically with a formula, but I want to understand how to solve it conceptually, I know it has to do with symmetry.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Red dots are on the 14th row (calculating from the blue dot, the first row is the 0th row).

Comment: I guessed wrong about the location of the red(s).

Comment: I've corrected the right answer there was a small error in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting André Nicolas: Consider the two points where the figures meet. Call them $P$ and $Q$.
In order to reach $P$, you have to go six times right up and five times right down, so you can reach $P$ in $\binom{11}{5}$ ways, and the same holds for $Q$. Once you have reached $P$ or $Q$, after three steps (at every step, you can go up or down) you reach a red point. Hence the number of paths is given by:
$$ 2\binom{11}{5}\cdot 2^3 = 7392.$$

Comment: Are you able to explain why $N(\text{top to middle}) * N(\text{from middle to P or Q}) * N(\text{from P or Q to red})=2^6*2^5*2^3$ is incorrect?

Comment: @Bright: in the topmost and downmost points you do not have two choices but only one, for instance.